# Java Hotspot Error - V [libjvm.so+0x5c3a84]

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I am having real problems getting to the bottom of the java hotspot errors we are experiencing. The errors are seemingly random and the problematic frame varies. An example error is shown below:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f65ce3c3a84, pid=26082, tid=0x00007f65bc2ab700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5c3a84]  G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space(InCSetState, oopDesc*, markOopDesc*)+0x174
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/dap/domains/tc0419/prod1/tomcat/bin/core or core.26082 (max size 1 kB). To ensure a full core dump, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

The java application is a relatively simple, it is just a war file running in a tomcat on a server.

Please let me know if any additional information would be helpful to access, I'm a bit new to this. The current thinking is that this is a hardware issue but any further information would be much appreciated.

Comment: It could be bug in JVM, should report to oracle

Comment: _"If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp"_

Comment: Also consider upgrading your JVM, the latest is Java 8 update 121.

Answer (score 1):

The problematic frame "G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space(InCSetState, oopDesc*, markOopDesc*)+0x174" represents it is an gc crash. It is bug in JVM. There are couple of issues reported before 
1. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170451
2. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143310
As we don't have way to reproduce or they occured once in a while. As you can see both the issues are closed either as Incomplete or cannot reproduce.
If you have a strong reproduce kindly file a bug through http://bugreport.java.com/submit_intro.do along with steps/test case to reproduce the issue.
It will be addressed... :)
You are using JDK 8 update 101, Kindly upgrade to latest build JDK8 update 121 from here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: I came across same crash when I develop fury: https://github.com/alipay/fury/pull/923#issuecomment-1744990145. It can be reproduced under ubuntu22 and jdk11. Linked the reproduction code under: https://github.com/alipay/fury/pull/923#issuecomment-1745035339

Comment: I have requested to file this issue in https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/ to one of the engineers at Oracle. Will let you know, once it is filed.

Comment: It is this - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8317577